# difference between two methods for selecting image from gallery in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In order to pick image from gallery, I found two solutions.

Method 1.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_PICK_FROM_ALBUM);
```

Method 2.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_PICK_FROM_ALBUM);
```

to test them in my phone(JellyBean. 4.1.2), both methods give identical result.
what is the recommended way to pick image from gallery in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public static final String CONTENT_TYPE
>
> Added in API level 1 The MIME type of of this directory of images.
>   Note that each entry in this directory will have a standard image MIME
>   type as appropriate -- for example, image/jpeg.
>
> Constant Value: "vnd.android.cursor.dir/image"

They are the same but go for first one using docs values (if the value is changed, you don't have to rewrite that line)